# vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I'm configuring ftp on a linux server.

This is my vsftpd.conf

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=Yes
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=10100
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
```

And yhis is the vsftp.chroot_list content

```
ftp
wp_ftp
```

Comment: If you do not know which line is causing the problem, the divide and conquor. Comment out some lines and retry until you find the one.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

This should give you the real error.